# Django NoReverseMatch and Django-Verify-Email

Tags: python, django, email-validation

I hope someone can help me with this bug.
So, I am using Django-Verify-Email as a library to send verifications emails from my app, and, according to the wiki, they use the LOGIN_URL variable in the settings of the app. The problem is that, at the moment, I want to change this LOGIN_URL to the homepage ('index'or '/' or 'mainpage') but it throws me a error (Django 3.2). Any help is apreciatted!

`Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index 'is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Index is at the core of the project, and not inside any app.

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
import user.urls
from .views import index
import calculator.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='mainpage'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Try `LOGIN_URL = 'mainpage'`

Comment: Already did it. The problem keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you placed your templates inside a folder of the templates folder, you need to tell the renderer where the page actually is by doing so as a redirect:

```
return redirect (request, 'folder_name:index')
```

Or you can simply render it to the desired page, like so:

```
return render(request, "folder_name/index.html", {})
```